# De un fichero con nombres y edades, que muestre por pantalla los nombres y edades superiores a 18 años

Tags: java, eclipse

estoy haciendo un programa con ficheros, dentro del fichero tengo un archivo txt con nombres y edades, en mi caso (Juan 20,Gabriel 10), y necesito un programa que me muestre todos los nombres y edades de aquellas personas que superan los 18 años, he conseguido que se me muestre todo lo que contiene el fichero pero no soy capaz de que me muestre solo el nombre y la edad de loa mayores de 18 años, lo estoy realizando en java, eclipse.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.FileReader; 
java.io.IOException; 

public class Ejercicio2 { 
    public static void muestraContenido(String archivo) throws 
FileNotFoundException, IOException { 
        String cadena; 
        FileReader f = new FileReader(archivo); 
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f); 
        while((cadena = b.readLine())!=null) { 
            System.out.println(cadena); 
        } 
        b.close(); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        muestraContenido("datos/edad.txt"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`split()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/) es un método que fragmenta una cadena en base a un expresión dentro de esa cadena

al tu tener los datos de ejemplo:

```
Juan 20,Gabriel 10,Sergio 30
```

tanto el nombre como la edad estan limitadas por una expresión (","), al usar split(",") obtendrás esos valores en un array de tipo String

```
String[] parts=["Juan 20","Gabriel 10","Sergio 30"];
parts[0]="Juan 20";
parts[1]="Gabriel 10";
parts[2]="Sergio 30";
```

cada parte sera una una nueva cadena y esta limita por un espacio(" ") por lo cual puedes volver a aplicar `split()` para separar el nombre de la edad

```
for(String part:parts){
   String[] data=part.split(" ")
}
```

lo siguiente es guardar esos datos obtenidos en una base ,puedes usar un array de nombre y otro de edades o podrias hacer uso de [`hashMap()`](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp) el cual  permite almacenar elementos en pares " clave / valor ".

```
HashMap<String(nombres), Integer(edades)> hashMap= new HashMap<>();
```

Ahora debería recorrer el hashMap evaluando el valor >18 para imprimir solo esos datos.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;




public class Ejercicio1 {
   public static void muestraContenido(String archivo) throws 
        FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String cadena;

        FileReader f = new FileReader(archivo);
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(f);
        HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap= new HashMap<>();
        while ((cadena = b.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = cadena.split(",");
            for(String part:parts){
                String[]data=part.split(" ");
                String nombre=data[0];
                int edad=Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
                hashMap.put(nombre,edad);                  
            }

                 for (HashMap.Entry<String, Integer> entrada : hashMap.entrySet()) {
                       if(entry.getValue()>18){
                            System.out.println(entrada);
                       }
                     }
            
              
            }
       b.close();
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Dramaturgo no daba con la solución y ya me dolía la cabeza de pensar

Comment: Esa es la idea mi estimado,te costara al principio pero ya veras que le agarraras la onda,recuerda que mi respuesta no es la única forma de resolución,  intenta desarrollarlo de otra manera,esfuérzate y practica..saludos